# Broken Duplicate

Tags: bug, questions, duplicate-questions, broken-link

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159683/namespaces-are-one-honking-great-idea-lets-do-more-of-those-why is closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228181/the-zen-of-python).

This gives users a broken link when they click on the duplicate link. This is probably not intentional.

Comment: Also loosely related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173351/166899

Comment: Lol. You close voted your own question. That's the way to go :)